# How do I turn builder rough-in plumbing into a basement bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, basement

Our house is nearly complete and I am planning our next steps. We have plumbing rough-in pipes for a basement bathroom, and to save some money I am planning on doing the bathroom myself over the next few weeks/months. I have done a decent bit of googling and have yet to find a tutorial that shows how I can go from rough-in to bathroom.

Q: What are the steps I need to take in order to create a bathroom from the rough-in pipes, and is there an instructional resource I can follow along with?

Details:

- The framing is already done since the rest of the basement is finished
- The floor will be tile
- The sink will be a pedestal
- I am considering putting in a utility sink instead of a shower and making it so it can be swapped out for a shower if we sell. Anything I should know there?

Comment: Just bring out your supply and drain for the utility sink where they'll be hidden by a shower so you don't have finish drywall work to deal with. You can always cut open the drywall behind the shower surround to reconfigure later.

Comment: is your drain pipe low enough that the shower won't need to be three feet off the floor (and thus 4 feet from the ceiling?

Comment: Yeah, it's new construction, and all of the rough-in includes drainage already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given what we know (virtually nothing), the question is too broad. Order of operations depends on a number of design and product choices. Here's a rough outline.

1. Frame the walls. Be sure that your toilet flange is centered 12" from framing. Be sure that your other plumbing and cabinetry plans fit as expected.
2. Run plumbing through the walls for your fixtures. Cap pipe stubs.
3. Rough in electrical.
4. Insulate and install vapor barrier as appropriate.
5. Install tub or shower pan. Install shower surround if it goes against framing.
6. Install drywall. Tape. Texture. Paint.
7. Install flooring and cabinetry in the desired order. Depends on flooring which comes first. Ceramic tile tends to go in after cabinetry. Vinyl may go in before.
8. Install trim woodwork (doors, casing, base, shoe).
9. Install electrical devices and trim.
10. Install shower surround if it goes over drywall.